# three.js script won't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm reading a book "Learning Three.js - The JavaScript 3D Library for WebGL - 2nd Edition" and first example in book which is not working at all.

Can someone please give me a direction why? I'd tried with ["How can I enable WebGL in my browser?"](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser) and it didn't help. But examples on [three.js / examples](http://threejs.org/examples/) are working as they should.

I've extracted three.js and put example bellow in build folder where three.js is located.

Do I need local web server to test WebGL?

Now I try to debug and code in Visual Code. Any other recommendations?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 01.02 - First Scene</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColorHex();
        renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE));
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // show axes in the screen
        var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
        scene.add(axes);

        // create the ground plane
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 20);
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc});
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

        // rotate and position the plane
        plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
        plane.position.x = 15;
        plane.position.y = 0;
        plane.position.z = 0;

        // add the plane to the scene
        scene.add(plane);

        // create a cube
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

        // position the cube
        cube.position.x = -4;
        cube.position.y = 3;
        cube.position.z = 0;

        // add the cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);

        // create a sphere
        var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x7777ff, wireframe: true});
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

        // position the sphere
        sphere.position.x = 20;
        sphere.position.y = 4;
        sphere.position.z = 2;

        // add the sphere to the scene
        scene.add(sphere);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // render the scene
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    window.onload = init;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the examples on the website are based on the latest release. the examples in the book are probably from an older release. but if the website examples work, webgl is enabled in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Now I found an error (Uncaught TypeError: renderer.setClearColorHex is not a function) in:
renderer.setClearColorHex();

and I also found  a link with the same problem  https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/issues/13. Was function setClearColorHex() ever working?

Comment: you are going to find many discrepancies between versions of the library. I would suggest using the latest version and trying to figure out what changed between the versions which is documented at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration

Comment: You could do as @gaitat suggested, but if you want to stick with the examples from your book you could also download an older version that corresponds to the examples in the book. You can download all older three.js releases **[here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases)**

Comment: not always but running a local server is good you can use wamp server, easy to use. You probably running new version of three.js( r77 for now), but book is based on r69.

Comment: "Do I need local web server to test WebGL"  No.  Threejs/WebGL runs in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

the line

> renderer.setClearColorHex()

should be removed.

Here is new code with a jsfiddle (using three.js from the net):

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Example 01.02 - First Scene</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
    <div id="WebGL-output">
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
      function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        //renderer.setClearColorHex();
        renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE));
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // show axes in the screen
        var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
        scene.add(axes);

        // create the ground plane
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 20);
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xcccccc
        });
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

        // rotate and position the plane
        plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
        plane.position.x = 15;
        plane.position.y = 0;
        plane.position.z = 0;

        // add the plane to the scene
        scene.add(plane);

        // create a cube
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xff0000,
          wireframe: true
        });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

        // position the cube
        cube.position.x = -4;
        cube.position.y = 3;
        cube.position.z = 0;

        // add the cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);

        // create a sphere
        var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x7777ff,
          wireframe: true
        });
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

        // position the sphere
        sphere.position.x = 20;
        sphere.position.y = 4;
        sphere.position.z = 2;

        // add the sphere to the scene
        scene.add(sphere);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // render the scene
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      window.onload = init;

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90zzka64/